# How do I secure a mine?

Tags: 7-days-to-die

I learned it the hard way that this game has extensive physics and tunnels and buildings can actually collapse. Since I recently finally acquired the plans for the forge, I am looking to get some ores going and want to start some mining.

I read in various other places that it would be wise to secure the mine with supports. Now my question is, what are supports and how do I place them best to prevent any tunnel from collapsing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General rules of thumb, from countless roofs collapsing on me, when building structures with cheap materials:

- Weight constraints are really well simulated. Use arches whenever possible if you try to build (or excavate) big structures. It will help increase the maximum weight your structures can support without breaking.
- If multiple mine levels, stack pillars on top of each other. (Because you definitely don't want heavy weight placed right in the middle of a roof.)
- If possible, use harder materials wherever supports are needed. (Wood is sturdier than soil, rock is sturdier than wood, etc...)
- Keep in mind that some materials are heavier than others, thus will need more supports. (That's the reason why you usually only use stone for vertical supports, and wood for non-vertical ones.)

---

When building a stone arch:

- Use a plain wooden support.
- Build the stone part.
- Remove the wooden support.

If constructed correctly, the stone arch should not collapse.

Comment: How often do you need the supports? How many blocks can I build without any?

Comment: It depends of 2 things: how much weight the roof of your mine will need to support, and how are the geological strata on top of it arranged (because they may, or may not, support each others). Short answer: I cannot state a precise value. However, i can say for sure that rooms larger than 5 blocks in width tend to collapse with more ease if you don't use arches, but only vertical suports.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that each block has a mass and a max load value which indicates it's breaking point. when I mine I only ever dig tunnels 3 wide and 4-5 high and those never needed a single support yet. Careful though if you are tunneling below a structure as the empty space right below a house could lead to you needing more support blocks in the structure. The [7 Days To Die wiki](http://7daystodie.gamepedia.com/) has great information on block mass, max loads, durability and how they are calculated as well.

Answer (score 1):

Mining a tunnel is more or less safe, however there are some things to keep in mind.

Be careful if you are thinking of mining big rooms, as mining too big without supports will cause your mine to collapse on your head and possibly kill you. To counteract this make sure you leave support pillars.
From http://7daystodie.gamepedia.com/Mining#Mining_Notes
I have never played this game. Just wanted to help, and the bounty helped encourage, even though I know I wont get the bounty.